# "word # of string" idiom (part of extended string functions)

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I'm trying to label variables in a `forvalues` loop on Stata version 11.2.

However, I can't get the extended string function `word # of string` idiom to work:

```
local names `""Growth" "Mature" "All""'

forvalues i = 0/2 {
    local name : word `i' of `names'
    display "`name'"
}
```

This follows a [Statalist solution](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2010-04/msg00941.html), but I keep getting `invalid syntax` errors.

I also tried `local names Growth Mature All`, but that doesn't work either.

Is there a way to do this algorithmically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`word 0` won't work. Stata starts counting at `1`.  Change your loop to `1/3` and it will work.

Also, consider `tokenize`:

```
. tokenize `""Growth" "Mature" "All""'

. forval i = 1/3 { 
  2.         di "``i''" 
  3. } 
Growth
Mature
All
```

`tokenize` splits a string into tokens, meaning words separated by spaces unless quotation marks bind words together. The tokens have names `1`, `2`, `3`. As you go round the loop, `i` is first `1`, so the request is to display the first macro, etc.